# Get DateTime corresponding to last Thu or Fri or Mon etc in SQL Server 2012

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

I have a certain DATETIME value, and I would like to get the DATETIME value for a given  weekday  'n' (where n is an integer from 1 thru to 7) that is just before the  given date.

**Question**: How would I do this given a value for currentDate and a value for lastWeekDay?

For example, if given date is 06/15/2015 in mm/dd/yyyy format, then what is the date for a weekday of 6 that came just before 06/15/2015.  In this example, given date is on Monday and we want the date for last Friday (i.e. weekday =6).

```
declare @currentDate datetime, @lastWeekDay int;
set @currentDate = getdate();
set @lastWeekDay = 6;--this could be any value from 1 thru to 7
select @currentDate as CurrentDate, '' as LastWeekDayDate --i need to get this date
```

**UPDATE 1**

In addition to the excellent answer by Anon, I also found an alternate way of doing it, which is as given below.

```
DECLARE @currentWeekDay INT;
SET @currentWeekDay = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @currentDate);

--Case 1: when current date week day > lastWeekDay then subtract 
--        the difference between the two weekdays
--Case 2: when current date week day <= lastWeekDay then go back 7 days from
--        current date, and then add (lastWeekDay - currentWeekDay)

SELECT
  @currentDate AS CurrentDate,
  CASE
    WHEN @currentWeekDay > @lastWeekDay THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ABS(CAST(@lastWeekDay AS INT) - CAST(@currentWeekDay AS INT)), @currentDate)
    ELSE DATEADD(DAY, @lastWeekDay - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, -7, @currentDate)), DATEADD(DAY, -7, @currentDate))
  END AS LastWeekDayDate;
```

Comment: Is it for a particular year or for any year?

Comment: No. The given data is current data and a week day.

Comment: So, if the given date is 04/17/2015 and lastWeekDay =4, then the result is 15th Apr 2015. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. But I am looking for a general solution and not just the one for this case that you mentioned.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to figure out the date for a given weekday number that contains the date you pass in? In other words, given a datetime you want to know get the day of the week passed in?

Comment: I know a date value, and I want to get the date value for last Friday or last Wed or last Thu etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate how many days have passed since a fixed date, modulo 7, and subtract that from the input date.  The magic number '5' is because Date Zero (1900-01-01) is a Monday. Shifting that forward 5 days makes the @lastWeekDay range [1..7] map to the range of weekdays [Sunday..Saturday].

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,-DATEDIFF(day,5+@lastWeekDay,@currentDate)%7,@currentDate)
```

I avoid the `DATEPART(weekday,[...])` function because of [`SET DATEFIRST`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks so much. I was missing out on some edge cases, but your T-SQL handles it perfectly and solves all edge cases.